# Modify Url from Search Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii2

I've search form that have part like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxlist-field-[29]" name="CategoryField[9][]" checked="checked" value="bed">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxlist-field-[30]" name="CategoryField[9][]" checked="checked" value="almari pakaian">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxlist-field-[31]" name="CategoryField[9][]" value="tv">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxlist-field-[32]" name="CategoryField[9][]" checked="checked" value="ac">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxlist-field-[33]" name="CategoryField[9][]" checked="checked" value="wifi-internet">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxlist-field-[34]" name="CategoryField[9][]" checked="checked" value="meja cermin rias">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxlist-field-[36]" name="CategoryField[9][]" checked="checked" value="sekamar berdua">
```

When they're checked and form is submited, it generates url into something like this :

```
http://localhost/index.php/category/akomodasi?CategoryField[9][]=bed&CategoryField[9][]=almari pakaian&CategoryField[9][]=ac&CategoryField[9][]=wifi-internet&CategoryField[9][]=meja cermin rias&CategoryField[9][]=bisa pasutri&CategoryField[9][]=sekamar berdua&CategoryField[10]=1
```

The search works fine, but I want to modify the url into something like this :

```
http://localhost/index.php/category/akomodasi?CategoryField[9]=bed,almari pakaian,ac,wifi-internet,meja cermin rias,bisa pasutri,sekamar berdua&CategoryField[10]=1
```

So values of CategoryField[9] are separated with ",".

How to modify the url? btw, I'm using Yii2 Framework.

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do with just form. You'll have to use Ajax for that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to get the category fields separated with ","? or actually need to change the url? If it's the first option you can do that with:

```
$categoryField = implode(', ', $_GET['CategoryField'][9]);
```

Comment: no, it's not first option. I need to modify the url. thanks